# vscode c# debugger was not attached within the expected time limit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm running vscode version 1.73.1
I have the following extensions installed on a new VM that sits behind a corporate proxy:

- Microsoft C# v1.25.2
- Azurite v3.20.1
- Azure Functions v1.9.0

I have a C# Azure Functions project that I'd like to debug.

My tasks.json file contains the following:

```json
 {
        "type": "func",
        "dependsOn": "build (functions)",
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net6.0"
        },
        "command": "host start --dotnet-isolated-debug",
        "isBackground": true,
        "problemMatcher": "$func-dotnet-watch"
      }
```

The launch.json is as follows:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Attach to .NET Functions",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:azureFunctions.pickProcess}"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I click the debug icon from the sidebar menu and choose "Run and Debug - Attach to .Net Functions"

The function app is then build and starts. The VM is slow so it takes more than 60 seconds for the function app to start. During that time VS code pops up a message to say is it slow. However, the function app does start and the http endpoints are presented in green text.

I then see the following presented in the terminal window:

> Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 12116) initialized in debug mode.
> Waiting for debugger to attach... Host lock lease acquired by instance
> ID '00000000000000000000000083B41702'. A debugger was not attached
> within the expected time limit. The process will continue without a
> debugger. Worker process started and initialized.

I don't see any text in the "Debug Console"

I am able to call the http endpoint and a successful response is returned, but the breakpoint does not break!

If I run the same solution in vs code directly on my laptop, then the debugger is attached. Problem is, I need to debug on the corporate VM because the code selects from an on-prem sql db.

So, I guess there must be some difference between the two configurations of vs code / extensions or perhaps the corporate proxy is causing a problem?

Comment: Does your project contain a launch.json file?

Comment: Hi Ross, yes, I have now updated the question with the launch.json

Comment: Not sure if it works with all projects, however, there is a debugger wait timeout setting that can be defined in the launch.json for launch/debug --> "timeout": 60 <-- to wait one minute. Give that a try and let us know if it works.

Comment: try deleting the "Releases" folder and restart the VS Code IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which text file this gets saved to but was able to resolve by extending the timeout in the workspace preferences section:

[image]

I increased from the default of 60 (seconds) to 180